# Intermediate calculations inside initialization list

Tags: c++

I have something like

```
struct Foo {
    const double a;
    const double b;
    Foo(double c);
}

Foo::Foo(double c) {
    double tmp = f(c);
    a = g(tmp);
    b = h(tmp);
}
```

where `f,g,h` are functions implemented elsewhere. This gives the expected "uninitialized const member" error.

I could fix it with

```
Foo::Foo(double c): a (g(f(c))), b (h(f(c))) {}
```

but `f` is an expensive function and I wouldn't like to run it twice.

My question is, how can I solve this problem without running `f` twice or making `tmp` a permanent member of `Foo`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically, delegating constructors offer a simple solution to this type of problem. In this case you'll have to introduce some way to distinguish between the two constructors:

```
private:
  // the int param is unused
  Foo(double fc, int) : a(g(fc)), b(h(fc)) {}

public:
  Foo(double c) : Foo(f(c), 0) {}
```